# Remove a node from its old parent's children with Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-structures, tree

BACKGROUND
I am writing a class in Ruby named PolyTreeNode which represents a node in a tree.

STEPS TAKEN
So far, I've been able to make it instantiate a new node where the parent = nil and there are no children. I have also been able to set a new parent and add the self to the new parent's children (unless the self is already included in the array).

PROBLEM
I would like to remove the self from the old parent's children when (re)assigning a new parent.

\
class PolyTreeNode

```
attr_reader :parent, :children, :value

def initialize(value)
    @value = value
    @parent = nil
    @children = []
end

def parent=(parent)
    if parent == nil
        @parent = nil
    else
        @parent = parent 
        parent.children << self unless parent.children.include?(self)
    end
end
```

\\

The way I wrote it was as follows but I am getting an RSPEC error.

```
def parent=(parent)
        if parent == nil
            @parent = nil
        else
            @parent = parent 
            parent.children << self unless parent.children.include?(self)
            @parent.children.delete(self)
        end
    end
´´´

Any ideas? Thanks!
```

Comment: What RSpec error do you get? How does your test look like?

Comment: You have to call `@parent.children.delete(self)` _before_ assigning the new parent via `@parent = parent`. Otherwise, you'll remove `self` from the new parent.